# Writing multiple files of same data amount vs writing a single large file of same data amount

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a big file to the local disk.
I split the big file into many small files and I tried to write it to the disk. But I observed that when I split the files and tried to write, there was a big increase in disk write time.

Also, I copy the files from a disk and write it another computer's disk(reducer). I observed that there was a big increase in read time as well. Can anybody explain me the reason? I am working with hadoop.

Thanks!

Comment: are you splitting and writing in the same file?

Comment: How big of a buffer are you writing?

Comment: Copying a big file is faster than copying many small files adding upto same size. This can be because after copying every file, it has to load the next file to copy. But in case of a big file, everything is loaded at once. So its done faster. I'm not sure of this; thats why leaving it as a comment.

Comment: No, I am not writing in the same file. I am writing to numerous new small files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to the underlying file system and hardware.

There's overhead for each file in addition to its contents, for example MFT for NTFS(on Windows). So for a single large file the file system could do less bookkeeping.Thus it's faster.

As arranged by your OS, single big file tends to be written on consecutive sectors of the hard drive where possible, but multiple small files may or may not be written as such. So the resulting increased seek time may account for the increased reading time for many small files.

The efficiency of your OS may also play a big part. For example whether it prefetches file contents, how it makes use of buffer, etc. For many small files it's more difficult for the OS to use the buffer(and deal with other issues) efficiently.(Under different scenarios it can behave differently.)

EDIT: As for the copy process you mentioned, generally your OS do it in the following steps:

read data from disk->writing data to buffer->read from buffer->write to (possibly another) disk

This is usually done in multiple threads. When dealing with many small files, the OS may fail to coordinate these threads efficiently(Some threads are very busy, while others must wait). For a single large file the OS doesn't have to deal with these issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I trying to understand a scenario where data is copied from Distributed File Sytem(HDFS), and written to induvidual local discs. Is there any difference in reading from HDFS?

Answer (score 3):

**Every file system has a smallest unit(non sharable) defined to store the data named page.** Say for example, in the file system, you have a page size of 4KB. Now if you save a big file of 8 KB, it will consume 2 pages on the disk. But if you break the file in 4 files, each of size 2KB, then it will consume 4 half filled pages on the disk consuming size 16KB disk space.

Similarly, if you break the file in 8 small files, each of size 1KB, then it will consume 8 pages in the disk though partially filled and your 32KB of the disk space is consumed.

Same is true in the reading overhead. If your file as several pages, then might be scattered. This will lead into high overhead in seektime/access time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you tell me about reading from many files from distributed file systems(HDFS), and writing to local discs?